# Keep Figures RIGHT AFTER text

Tags: floats

Im still searching and trying to manage with this float figures but with no success. I really need that my figures stay right at the place that they are called, not on the next page!
My document is something like this:

Executamos o algoritmo, geramos nossos dados e plotamos o nosso gráfico. Vide Figura ~\ref{fig:exampleFig5}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{alg3.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:exampleFig5}
\end{figure}

O resultado do gráfico não representa uma reta, logo, teremos que analisar o comportamento deste algoritmo. Aplicamos o log dos valores do eixo y e replotamos o gráfico. Vide Figura ~\ref{fig:exampleFig6}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{alg3y.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:exampleFig6}
\end{figure}

Com o grafico gerado, continuamos sem saber a característica deste algoritmo. Vamos tirar o log do eixo x e novamente replotar o gráfico. Vide Figura ~\ref{fig:exampleFig7}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{alg3xy.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:exampleFig7}
\end{figure}

The text is in portuguese, but this doesnt matter. The question is: why the figures are going to the next page if i call them right after the text with this: [htbp] ?

Sorry, i dont know how to use the code format in this editor

Comment: If you don't want your `figure`s to float, then `\usepackage{float}` in your preamble and `\begin{figure}[H]` ... `\end{figure}` for your figures. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the package `\usepackage{float}` and insert `H` instead of `htbp`.

`H` places the float at precisely the location in the LaTeX code (from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)

Comment: Actually it really worked. I was trying to use h instead of H ... But it created some strange spaces before and after section number 5: http://puu.sh/nI3zW/31ec740528.png

Do you have any idea why this is happening?